# From list of strings, extract only characters within brackets

Tags: python

I have a list of strings that have variable construction but have a character sequence enclosed in square brackets. I want to extract only the sequence enclosed by the square brackets. There is only one instance of square brackets per string, which simplifies the process.

I am struggling to do so in an elegant manner, and this is clearly a simple problem with Python's large string library.

What is a simple expression to do this?

Comment: You need to provide an example

Comment: [`import re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check regular expression, "re"

Something like this should do the trick

```
import re

s = "hello_from_adele[this_is_the_string_i_am_looking_for]this_is_not_it"
match = re.search(r"\[([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\]", s)
print match.group(1)
```

If you provide an example, we can be more specific

Comment: Wouldn't be more generic saying: `"\[[^]]+\]"`

Comment: Yes, the inside depends on the strings, if we get examples, i can get more specific :)

Comment: @GáborErdős simpel's is actually *less* specific. Match everything inside `[]` except a `]`

Comment: @MattDMo YMMV, but I find regex to be the cleaner option.

Comment: @AdamSmith *Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions."  Now they have two problems.*

Comment: @MattDMo A pithy expression. Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use string slicing." Now they have an off-by-one error. :)

Comment: @AdamSmith which is what happened to me when I first tried the slicing in my answer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96185/discussion-between-adam-smith-and-mattdmo).

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need `re` to do this:

```
In [11]: strng = "This is some text [that has brackets] followed by more text"

In [12]: strng[strng.index("[")+1:strng.index("]")]
Out[12]: 'that has brackets'
```

This uses [string slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-slice) to return the characters inside the brackets. [`index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) returns the 0-based position of its argument. Since we don't want to include the `[` at the beginning, we add 1. The second argument of the slice is the stop position, but it is *not included* in the returned substring, so we don't need to add anything to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer not to use regex for whatever reason, it should be easy to do with string splitting since you're guaranteed to have one and only one instance of `[` and `]`.

```
s = "some[string]to check"

_, midright = s.split("[")
target, _ = midright.split("]")
```

or

```
target = s.split("[")[1].split("]")[0]  # ewww
```